# How to save data to show on other page

Tags: javascript, html, database, local-storage

I'm new in Javascript and programming and I have created a simple two-page E-commerce Site and I have a shopping Cart in it what I want is to save all the items that have been selected and show them when user go to the other page.
I have researched and I found there is a lot of ways to save data. like Database, cloud and local storage. what I wanna know is in my situation what should I use and if its local storage than it will really be helpful if there would be an example on how to save data that is inside function

Comment: sessionStorage you can directly use for cart and save data as json. You can try in example: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/create-client-side-shopping-cart/

Answer (score 0):

In your case, localStorage is recommended.
You should read the MDN documentation on this API : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage